# if(functionA() || functionB()).How it works in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have two functions: `functionA()` and `functionB()`, both have a return type `boolean`.

I want to continue my execution if either one of them returns true and if functionA returns true I don't want function B to execute.

As && works (if one is false it does not check the other), does || works the same?

```
if(functionA() || functionB()){
//Do Your Work
}
```

Will the above code satisfy my requirement?

Comment: Yes it will, as long as both functions return a `boolean`.

Comment: Why don't you try it out instead of wasting time asking a question here?

Comment: An answer that is proper will just state "Yes.". It is very easy to try this on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean f1 = functionA();
boolean f2 = functionB();

if(f1 || f2){
// if statement
} else {
// else statement
}
```

Comment: this is just sample code, not an answer to the question. Also it is not what the user asked, since it runs both functionA and functionB no matter if the result of functionA is true.

Answer (score 6):

As specified by the [Java Language Specification, §15.24](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24):

> The conditional-or operator || operator is like | ([§15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false.

Answer (score 3):

If your first function `returns true` then  `logical OR` short circuites your second function.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: "By default"? Can you change this behavior in Java??

Comment: @antti.huima Java also has the `&`/`|` _logical_ operators (not bitwise), which will evaluate _all_ conditions even if one is false/true. That is, these two operators do not short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will exactly do what you want. Run functionA() and if that does not return true run functionB()

Comment: you should choose Marko Topolnik's answer, he added a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy evaluation in java will avoid your `functionB()` if `functionA()` returns `true`.

```
if(functionA() | functionB())
```

Can get you through this mechanism and forces the evaluation of your two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will, if you wanted it to execute both you would have done `if(functionA() | functionB()){`

note, only one vertical bar

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely it will execute `function A()` and if it will return true then `function B()` will not run and you other code will be executed as u want.